sequence of middle authors in physics or engineering fields
There is a paper of multiple authors from several institutions:
student, ..., author, author,..., PI corresponding author.
The middle authors have equal contributions and are not corresponding authors. Among the middle authors, there's a senior author who's a big deal in a more generic field. Is there any strategy of ordering the middle authors?

I outlined one approach in this answer. Would that be suitable or are you trying to optimize for something specific?

The link posted by @Anyon summarizes the general approach. Start at the ends and work your way in. Lead authors (students and postdocs) at the front, correspond authors (PIs) at the back. Senior contributors (other faculty) closer to the PIs, other students/postdocs closer to the student/postdoc lead authors. The perceived order depending on how many authors is usually based on degree of contribution.... a lot of the times that is hard to assign, but the good news is that it is mostly meaningless outside of the minds of people obsessed with author order.

If  you are asking "how was it done?" then you need to ask them. If you are asking "how should it be done?" then this is a duplicate.

You have a similar question: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/213700/corresponding-author-not-as-the-last-author-in-physics-or-engineering

@Coder yes, but that can't help answer this one directly

@Anyon thanks that's quite helpful
