corresponding author not as the last author in physics or engineering
I'm talking in the context where alphabetical author listing is not applied. Some corresponding authors put themselves in the middle of the author list, what is the logic behind this? This happens often when a more senior author (than the corresponding author) is the put in the last position, but who is not a corresponding author.

"This happens often when a more senior author (than the corresponding author) is the put in the last position, but who is not a corresponding author." Isn’t that an answer to your question already?

another reason might be that the first author will leave the institution soon and will not be reachable by their department email adress.

https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4473/197929, second bullet point?

@MisterMiyagi  I think that's more of a phenomenon than an answer.

@feynman I don’t see why. The ordering "most senior last" seems like a perfectly valid ordering - which means the corresponding author isn’t necessarily last.

One potential answer is the existence of "transformative agreements" between some institutions and some publishers. Part of these agreements is often that authors from these institutions do not pay (individually) to publish their work as open access in the publisher's journals. Often the eligibility of a manuscript under these agreements is determined by the affiliation of the corresponding author.
Consequently, a group of authors may decide to make the collaborator with access to one of these agreements the corresponding author (especially in fields where no particular prestige is associated with the status of "corresponding author").

Yes, even in fields where the author ordering is based on contribution and/or seniority, corresponding author is often based on unrelated practical considerations, of which this is an important example.

Another possibility is that one author might be in a country where corresponding authorship is valued highly.

@Anyon  if so why is the corresponding author not at the last?

@feynman because the last author is the senior author, and if the corresponding author is not the senior author, they aren't going to be listed last.

@feynman Were they a PI or supervisor of the project? If not, then they conventionally wouldn't get the coveted last author spot. But if the corresponding author asterisk isn't worth much to the last author (sometimes all it gives you is more spam emails...), why not give it to an author working in a context where it's valued?

@Anyon they are perhaps not PIs otherwise they'll be listed corresponding.

@WhatTheDuck 'if the corresponding author is not the senior author, they aren't going to be listed last.' why is this?

@feynman Because the senior author is listed last. They are listed last because, in fields where authorship is not alphabetic, the last author in the list is understood to be the "supervisor" of the project (and many of the authors towards the back end of the list are similarly understood to be in supervisory roles on large author lists.) The corresponding author could be any of the authors and appear anywhere in the author list.  (1/2)

@feynman So the corresponding author will not be the last author listed, unless they are ALSO the senior author, in which case they are listed last because they are the senior author, not because they are the corresponding author. The corresponding author does not have to be the senior author. They could be an extremely junior member of the group. They could have contributed the least to the project. As such, the person designated to be the corresponding author can appear anywhere in the author list. (2/2)

Corresponding author is a job, not an honor. Authors can choose the most relevant person to handle inquiries about the paper. This is the PI in some fields, where the research is done under the direction of such a person and is the logical choice.
It is also common in such fields for the PI to be listed on most papers produced by the group, even when their direct participation in the individual paper is small (or even nonexistent).
So Corresponding Author as last author is just the intersection of those two common practices.
But the authors of a paper are free to choose the person they feel best able to handle those inquiries and they are also free to choose author order. So, across different fields and different traditions you will find a variety of things. Don't make assumptions. The two ideas are actually independent, even if they intersect in many cases.

Yes, looking at some of mine over the years we have a real mix (applied physics).  The corresponding author might be the first author (even if a postgrad), the first author's PI, the PI of the lead group on the grant, etc. Some journals are now grouping authors by institution (Phys. Rev. Res. for example) which does even strange things to ideas around the relative importance of authors

The convention in my field is the PI is the corresponding author and last on the author list. When there are multiple corresponding authors because of a collaboration, as is often the case, it is generally understood that the one listed last has the most authority over the project (typically their group spearheaded it).
At least in my field, when I have encountered a scenario of the lead PI not being the last author (when the last author was not even listed as corresponding "*") it was typically due to a deference to authority. My postdoctoral advisor was a huge figure in multiple fields. He would however collaborate generously, providing resources and contributing to the writing of manuscripts with earlier-career faculty. He would often decline any corresponding author status, but the others would often place him last on the list anyway as a sign of respect.

So this kind of respect does exist as I guessed, assuming that the last person is the authority regardless of whether they are the corresponding author.  Or could it be for another reason:  when no asterisk is used for the corresponding author, then the last author is assumed to be the corresponding author, then the last author in this case benefits from this?

@feynman "benefits" is a loaded word. At the time, my advisor was pushing 1000 publications (regularly in Science and Nature) and vying for Kavli/Wolf/Nobel. The only benefit is I guess my advisor felt good that he was appreciated by his collaborators. I think on his end inclusion on the paper was only a means to justify grant resources in support of the project, and less so on the personal gain end of things. I am so far off (currently mid-career, 6 figure papers, no global prizes on the horizon now or likely ever) where he was at that point that I really can't speak to his perspective on it.

R1NaNo if your advisor funded the paper, why wasn't he the corresponding author or even one of the co-corresponding

@feynman largely because he did not want to detract from the amount of credit the younger collaborator would get for that paper.

I'm pretty sure in physics & engineering, authors are listed by contribution. The first author does more work than the second author, who does more work than the third author, and so on.
Therefore, the question is kind of moot. The author order is fixed, the only question is who the most appropriate corresponding author is. Quite often that's the PI, because they're the most "static" person who can be expected to be working on similar problems for a long time. But it doesn't have to be: since the first author did most of the work, they're also the person best-positioned to answer questions on it (at least in the short term). In the end it's a question for the authors to decide.
